# How do I allow weak MD5 authentication for vpnc with NetworkManager?

Tags: networkmanager, vpn

I need to connect to a legacy Cisco VPN server that uses weak MD5 authentication. I have set up the connection in NetworkManager (1.40.10), but the underlying vpnc (0.5.3) fails to connect, complaining about the weak authentication:

```
NetworkManager[1234]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: Peer has selected md5 as authentication method.
NetworkManager[1234]: This algorithm is considered too weak today.
NetworkManager[1234]: If your vpn concentrator admin still insists on using md5,
NetworkManager[1234]: use the "--enable-weak-authentication" option.
```

I do not see any option in my NetworkManager connection settings to enable such thing, and I can't find any way to pass arbitrary command-line options to vpnc.

I have tried:

- Adding `Enable weak authentication=yes` in `/etc/vpnc/default.conf` or `/etc/vpnc.conf`: Does not work because NetworkManager passes the configuration through stdin to vpnc.
- Adding `Enable weak authentication=yes` to the NetworkManager connection configuration file: It fails saying that it is not a recongnized config option.
- ...As a workaround, I've created a shell script in `/usr/sbin/vpnc` that calls `/usr/sbin/real_vpnc --enable-weak-authentication "$@"`. This **WORKS** but this is clearly a fragile hack.

**How do I properly enable this option in Network Manager?**